# How to show a custom html page and view based page conditionally in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-view

I've generated an angular project using yeoman.

I had an index.html with ng-view and I was showing claims.html, claim-details.html through corresponding controllers and they get rendered in ng-view properly.

Now, I've a signin.html page with specific css and it's a full structured HTML page. I want to show this when user is not logged in. As soon as he's authenticated, he should be redirected to above said views. How can I configure this?

I've following routing

```
 app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/claims.html',
    controller: 'ClaimsCtrl'
  })
  .when('/signin', {
    templateUrl: 'views/signin.html',
    controller: 'SigninCtrl'
  })
  .when('/dashboard', {
    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
 });
```

Is it possible to mention, which .html should be rendered as part of ng-view and which should be a standalone html file? i.e. I want claims.html and dashboard.html to be part of ng-view, but signin.html should be standalone

Comment: I have not heard of this being possible. `ngView` serves as a placeholder to load current route's template. I don't think you can render anything outside the `ngView`. You can simulate `signin.html` to look like standalone, by placing `ngView` on `<html>` attribute and thus being able to change all of the page, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the '$stateChangeStart' event provided by [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)
This event is fired when the transition begins.
You could inject the service handling your user and redirect it if he is not logged. This would looks like this :

app.run(['$state', 'Session' function($state, Session){

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, from, fromParams){
    if (toState.name !== "login" && !Session.is_connected()) {
        $state.go("login");
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

}]);

Additionally, you could also save the last state he was trying to access and redirect him to it once he is logged in.

Comment: But, doing this way is injecting my signin.html file into index.html's ng-view. I want to avoid it. I want to show fully structured signin.html without ng-view in index.html

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJs project, I achieved this simply by injecting an Authentication service on each controller. In this service, I check if user is not authenticated or does not have enough privilege, if true then I simply do `$location.url("/login");` ([location service docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location))

Comment: but the template file given for /login is my signin.html, so it get's rendered in ng-view of index.html. I want it to be a seperate page - how to avoid injecting inside ng-view?

Comment: I see what you mean. Sounds like what you are, ultimately, looking to achieve is to redirect user to a separate page. Do so by calling `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com/signin.html");` when User is not Authenticated. Then on Login, direct user to your `ngView` page?

Comment: Updated routing code and mentioned what I wanna do in last 3 lines.